# Kotlin distinctBy with condition

Tags: kotlin

I have array with multiple objects with the same key, Other objects have empty values and I was hoping to use distinctBy to remove duplicates and get objects which values has the longest string.

```
data class ObjA(val key: String, val value: String)

fun test() {
    val listOfA = mutableListOf(
            ObjA("one", ""), //This will be taken in distinctBy.
            ObjA("one", "o"),
            ObjA("one", "on"),
            ObjA("one", "one"), //This will be ignored in distinctBy. I WANT THIS ONE.

            ObjA("two", ""), //This will be returned in distinctBy
            ObjA("two", "2"),
            ObjA("two", "two"), //But I want this.

            ObjA("three", "3"),
            ObjA("four", "4"),
            ObjA("five", "five")
    )

    val listOfAWithNoDuplicates = listOfA.distinctBy { it.key }

    for (o in listOfAWithNoDuplicates) {
        println("key: ${o.key}, value: ${o.value}")
    }
}
```

Output

```
key: one, value: 
key: two, value: 
key: three, value: 3
key: four, value: 4
key: five, value: five
```

How to make this work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [`distinctBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html) just returns the distinct keys based on your selector (and in the order of the list), you end up with unique keys, but not yet with the values you want.

For that particular use-case I would probably just [sort](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) beforehand, followed by the [`distinctBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html)

```
listOfA.sortedByDescending { it.value.length }
       .distinctBy { it.key }
```

Which creates a new list at [`sortedByDescending`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by-descending.html) or you just sort the current list beforehand ([`sortByDescending`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by-descending.html)) and apply `distinctBy` later on, e.g.:

```
listOfA.sortByDescending { it.value.length }
listOfA.distinctBy { it.key }
```

In both cases you get a new `List<ObjA>` with the expected values.

Several other variants come to my mind as well. All those variants will put the results into a `Map<String, ObjA>` where the key is actually the unique `ObjA.key`. You may want to call `.values` directly if you are not interested in the key/`ObjA`-mapping.

1. variant using [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) and [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html):

   ```
   listOfA.groupingBy { it.key }
          .reduce { _, acc, e->
            maxOf(e, acc, compareBy { it.value.length })
          }
   ```
2. variant using a plain [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html)/`for` and filling its own `Map`:

   ```
   val map = mutableMapOf<String, ObjA>()
   listOfA.forEach {
       map.merge(it.key, it) { t, u ->
           maxOf(t, u, compareBy { it.value.length })
       }
   }
   ```
3. variant using [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) and [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) (very similar to the previous... just using `fold` instead of `for`/`forEach`):

   ```
   listOfA.fold(mutableMapOf<String, ObjA>()) { acc, objA ->
     acc.apply {
       merge(objA.key, objA) { t, u ->
         maxOf(t, u, compareBy { it.value.length })
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. variant using [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) followed by [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) (but you are then actually creating 1 map which you discard immediately):

   ```
   listOfA.groupBy { it.key } // the map created at this step is discarded and all the values are remapped in the next step
          .mapValues { (_, values) ->
             values.maxBy { it.value.length }!!
          }
   ```

Comment: Thanks it worked. May you take a look at this one too. I want to process this list one more time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255964/removing-elements-from-a-list-which-are-not-in-another-list

Comment: Method 4 returns a map, If one needs a list at the end, need one more .values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxBy{}` like:

```
val x = listOfAWithNoDuplicates.maxBy { it.key.length }
println(x)
```

Output

`ObjA(key=three, value=3)`

Comment: will maxBy remove duplicates?

Comment: Thanks for response but this will return one object with highest length I guess. What I want is new array of objects which values will have highest value length and of course with duplicates removed as well!

Comment: ah ok. misunderstood :)