# Removing elements from a list which are not in another list - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two mutableLists, listOfA has so many objects including duplicates while listOfB has fewer. So I want to use listOfB to filter similar objects in listOfA so all list will have equal number of objects with equivalent keys at the end. Code below could explain more.

```
fun main() {
    test()
}

data class ObjA(val key: String, val value: String)
data class ObjB(val key: String, val value: String, val ref: Int)

fun test() {
    val listOfA = mutableListOf(
            ObjA("one", ""),
            ObjA("one", "o"),
            ObjA("one", "on"),
            ObjA("one", "one"),

            ObjA("two", ""),
            ObjA("two", "2"),
            ObjA("two", "two"),

            ObjA("three", "3"),
            ObjA("four", "4"),
            ObjA("five", "five")
    )

    //Use this list's object keys to get object with similar keys in above array.
    val listOfB = mutableListOf(
            ObjB("one", "i", 2),
            ObjB("two", "ii", 5)
    )

    val distinctListOfA = listOfA.distinctBy { it.key } //Remove duplicates in listOfA

    /*    
    val desiredList = doSomething to compare keys in distinctListOfA and listOfB
    for (o in desiredList) {
        println("key: ${o.key}, value: ${o.value}")
    }
    */

    /* I was hoping to get this kind of output with duplicates removed and comparison made.
      key: one, value: one
      key: two, value: two
     */
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to operate directly on that `distinctListOfA` you may want to use [`removeAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html) to remove all the matching entries from it. Just be sure that you initialize the keys of `B` only once so that it doesn't get evaluated every time the predicate is applied:

```
val keysOfB = listOfB.map { it.key } // or listOfB.map { it.key }.also { keysOfB ->
distinctListOfA.removeAll {
  it.key !in keysOfB
}
//} // if "also" was used you need it
```

If you have a `MutableMap<String, ObjA>` in place after evaluating your unique values (and I think it may make more sense to operate on a `Map` here), the following might be what you are after:

```
val map : MutableMap<String, ObjA> = ...
map.keys.retainAll(listOfB.map { it.key })
```

[`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) just keeps those values that are matching the given collection entries and after applying it the map now contains only the keys `one` and `two`.

In case you want to keep your previous lists/maps and rather want a new list/map instead, you may just call something like the following before operating on it:

```
val newList = distinctListOfA.toList() // creates a new list with the same entries
val newMap = yourPreviousMap.toMutableMap() // create a new map with the same entries
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You saved my day.

Comment: @Roland what if I needed to check for 2 keys in the object i.e. I want to remove all objects from listA which are present in listB with Key1 and Key2?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this

```
primaryList.removeAll { primaryItem ->
            secondaryList.any { it.equals(primary.id, true) }
        }
```

PrimaryList here is a list of objects 
SecondaryList here is a list of strings